# How to call json API specific keys

Tags: javascript, vue.js

can someone help me?
i have json like this

```
[ 
 { "positive": 2, "negative": 4 }, 
 { "positive": 9, "negative": 18 }, 
 { "positive": 6, "negative": 12 } 
]
```

---

But i want to change it like this

```
[2, 9, 6] and [4, 18, 12]
```

Comment: what do you mean by and? You want 2 arrays? And is not a valid javascript keyword.

Comment: positives: `arr.map(o => o.positive)`, negatives: `arr.map(o => o.negative)`. Or, using `lodash/map`: `import { map } from 'lodash-es'; const positives = map(arr, 'positive'); const negatives = map(arr, 'negative')`. Note: `arr` is your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way - tried and tested

```js
let data=[ 
 { "positive": 2, "negative": 4 }, 
 { "positive": 9, "negative": 18 }, 
 { "positive": 6, "negative": 12 } 
];

let new_d=[]

data.map((e,i,a)=>{Object.keys(e).map((e1,i1,a1)=>{new_d[e1]=[...new_d[e1]||[],e[e1]]})})

console.log(new_d)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use map function.

```js
var data = [ 
 { "positive": 2, "negative": 4 }, 
 { "positive": 9, "negative": 18 }, 
 { "positive": 6, "negative": 12 } 
];

const positiveList = data.map(({positive})=> positive);

const negativeList = data.map(({negative})=> negative);

console.log(positiveList);
console.log(negativeList);
```

Or you can merge into 1 map function.

```js
   var data = [ 
     { "positive": 2, "negative": 4 }, 
     { "positive": 9, "negative": 18 }, 
     { "positive": 6, "negative": 12 } 
    ];

    const [positiveList, negativeList] = data.reduce(([a,b], {positive,negative})=>{ 
      a.push(positive); 
      b.push(negative); 
      return [a,b]; 
    }, [[],[]]);


    console.log(positiveList);
    console.log(negativeList);
```

Comment: a for loop would be better since you can do it in 1 pass instead of 2.

Comment: Instead of two map, It will be better if you will use single map for better performance. Like your solution with reduce() method.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a simple forEach loop. Like that:

```js
const d = [ 
 { "positive": 2, "negative": 4 }, 
 { "positive": 9, "negative": 18 }, 
 { "positive": 6, "negative": 12 } 
]

const p = []
const n = []


d.forEach(e => {
  p.push(e.positive)
  n.push(e.negative)
})

console.log("+", p)
console.log("-", n)
```